# Detecting unused components in Wix in Visual Studio

Tags: wix

I'm using wix 3.8 in Visual Studio 2010.

If I have 2 components in a fragment in a wxs file and I only reference one of them in a feature I get an ICE21 error that there are components that are not used.

If I have a wxs file with components where none of the components are part of a feature I get no error, the components are just silently skipped.

Is this the desired behaviour? Is there a way to force an error message in this case?

The reason I'm asking is that I plan to use wix to create an installer where the developers themselves are reponsible for adding new files and components to the installer. It would be nice to have a way to make sure that they (we) didn't forget to include the new components in a feature.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment description [from the documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/fragment.html), I highlighted the part where it should answer your question:

> The Fragment element is the building block of creating an installer
>   database in WiX. Once defined, the Fragment becomes an immutable,
>   atomic unit which can either be completely included or excluded from a
>   product. The contents of a Fragment element can be linked into a
>   product by utilizing one of the many *Ref elements. **When linking in a
>   Fragment, it will be necessary to link in all of its individual units.
>   For instance, if a given Fragment contains two Component elements, you
>   must link both under features using ComponentRef for each linked
>   Component. Otherwise, you will get a linker warning and have a
>   floating Component that does not appear under any Feature.**

So, if any Component is referenced into a Feature then the complete Fragment with all its Components will be pulled into build and give you a warning/error that you have orphan component(s).

In your first case you have two components in a same fragment and you referenced only one and got an error about the second component.

If you have a fragment with many components and you don't reference any of them then Wix will not read that fragment at all.

In your second case all your components are in the same fragment but none of the components are referenced into a Feature therefore there are no errors as that fragment is not used at all.